# EU citizen living in London wants to bring non-EU citizen wife over

Tags: immigration, eu, family

I am an EU citizen with full settlement status. I got married to my spouse in Somalia some months ago and she recently moved and is residing in the UAE. She is a Somali national with a Somali passport. My question is what evidence/documents do I need to provide to the UK embassy in Dubai to bring her to live with me in the UK? I tried finding this information online but found it difficult, there are two types of forms on the UK Government website, but I'm not 100% sure which one to use.

Comment: You are an EU citizen and not a British citizen, correct?  Also, which forms are you looking at and why are you having trouble deciding which to use?

Comment: I don't mind voting to close this, but we need to know the OP's actual citizenship so we know which question this is a duplicate of (both the EU and UK versions have already been asked and answered on this forum).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your wife will need to apply for an [EEA family permit.](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit) Once in the UK, she should then apply for a [UK residence card](https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-a-uk-residence-card) (technically this isn't required, but it makes life a lot easier).

The pages linked here give quite detailed information on what you need to supply.

This assumes that you are a non-UK EU citizen - UK citizens have a different process.

Comment: I am a Swedish citizen. How long does it take to process and do I have to travel with her or if granted can she come into the UK by herself with the permit? Also what evidences does the EEA permit require to prove the marriage?